# Why Does Java Provide Specification Instead of Implementation

Tags: java, specifications

Why does Java not provide a "standard" implementation for all APIs? For example, JPA, XML, Transformers, and more!

Wouldn't it be more convenient if there was an implementation and if people didn't like it then they could rely on other libraries which implement the interfaces

Comment: Not sure the company strategy is really on topic...

Comment: What is the point of Java ? To be cross-plateform, what is the best solution for that, let every plateform build the own API using the interface provided. Imagine the JDBC with a "standard" implementation, welcome in hell ;)

Comment: In many cases, they do provide an implementation, however there is no commercial reason to provide implementations for them all.

Comment: An implementation is not a specification, and it leaves the actual specification at guess (specifically if the implementation changes). In contrast a specification allows multiple conforming implementations. Maybe your question is actually why the specification is not useful to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sun did provide reference implementations for many of their specifications (e.g. Glassfish).  But not all.

Sun was a hardware company first - they sold servers.

Java was intended to drive server sales, not corner a software market.  They thought their interests would be better served by writing specifications that anyone could implement and compete with.

JPA is an interesting one because object-relational mapping implementations like TOPLink, preceded the specification by many years.  Message queues existed before JMS was written.

Comment: I like the "History part" here. Oracle is still mostly a Database hardware/software provider I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking here - but for instance the reference implementation for JPA is EclipseLink, and GlassFish provides reference implementations for JAX-WS and JAXB.

Answer (score 0):

They do. Having a Reference Implementation is part of the Final Release of a JSR.
See the JCP overview https://jcp.org/en/procedures/overview
and the FAQ https://jcp.org/en/introduction/faq#ri
for more information on that.